# rails 3 order by another models column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have 2 models in my Rails 3 app which I use to describe people and where they live
Unfortunately I set these up without using associations

The 2 tables are setup like this

```
People
 id
 name
 location_id

Locations
  id
  name
```

what I want to do is list all entries in the Peoples table ordered by Locations.name alphabetically and People.name alphabetically

I can do a simple sort using this code which groups each person by a location but I need to drill into the Locations table as well

```
@people = People.all(:order => '"location_id" ASC, "name" ASC')
```

Anyone have any idea?

Also is it a good idea to set up an association in the People class to say location_id is Locations.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
belongs_to :location
```

To the People class

Then you can query the following way:

```
@people = People.joins(:location).order("locations.name ASC, people.name ASC")
```